# QT 4.8.4 debug libraries not found on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, debugging, libraries

I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.2.
I installed both Qt libraries 4.8.4 for Mac (185 MB) and debug libraries (480 MB) from http://qt-project.org/downloads

When I try to debug an application in Qt Creator (2.6.2) I get the following lines in the application output:

```
Unable to read symbols for QtSql.framework/Versions/4/QtSql (file not found).
Unable to read symbols from "QtSql" (not yet mapped into memory).
Unable to read symbols for QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (file not found).
Unable to read symbols from "QtCore" (not yet mapped into memory).
Unable to read symbols for QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (file not found).
Unable to read symbols from "QtGui" (not yet mapped into memory).
Unable to read symbols for QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (file not found).
Unable to read symbols from "QtNetwork" (not yet mapped into memory).
```

The files mentioned above exist.
The two debug windows stay empty all the time, only the mouse turns to a clock when I move it over the windows.

The only thing I get is the right position in the code if the application crashes.

Thanks for your help!
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just had the problem. I solved this by changing the debugger dbg by lldb.