# Unable to run Qt debugger on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, debugging

Trying to debug an application written in Qt on mac (10.6.8). Qt 4.8.6, QtCreator 3.2.0,  I set up the debugger System GDB at `/usr/bin/gdb` and compiler gcc-4.2

I want to debug the code...

I get in the application output window

```
Debugging starts
Debugging has failed
Debugging has finished
```

(and no breakpoints were hit, nothing has started in code)

I opened the debug log window, and the only suspicious things I saw were

```
....
    111^error,msg="Undefined command: \"python\". Try \"help\*.*
    NOTE: ENGINE SETUP FAILED
    State Changed From EngineSetupRequested(1) to EngineSetupFailed(2)
    HANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
    .....
```

On the left, some of the commands had

```
109-interpreter-exec console "python sys.path.insert(1, "/Volumes/QtCreator/..."
110-interpreter-exec console "python sys.path.append("/usr/bin/data-directory/ python)"
111-interpreter-exec console "python from gdbbridge import *"
```

I checked that python is installed... i can type python from anywhere and get its command prompt so it is on system path...

I read something about having to sign a fsf debugger but the one I am using is not a fsf debugger ?

What can I do to debug my apps in macx ?

**Edit:** Tried gdb from command line, with the app as argument

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
...
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin"...
warning: Unable to read symbols for QtSvg.framework/Versions/4/QtSvg (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "QtSvg" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for QtGui.framework/Versions/4/QtGui (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "QtGui" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for QtCore.framework/Versions/4/QtCore (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "QtCore" (not yet mapped into memory).
warning: Unable to read symbols for QtNetwork.framework/Versions/4/QtNetwork (file not found).
warning: Unable to read symbols from "QtNetwork" (not yet mapped into memory).
Reading symbols for shared libraries .
... some warnings that .o is more recent than .dylib in dependent libs... but that I don't have to step into so I don't care...
...
warning: Could not find object file "/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin11/4.2.1/x86_64/crt3.o" - no debug information available for "darwin-crt3.c".
.... done
```

So I type run

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x00007fff83872c00 in strlen ()
```

I don't know where that is (I do but really can't see it) or if it is an actual string pointer or something else...

I don't know where the breakpoints would be, the entire source is very long and contains lots and lots of files so I really don't know how I can do it with gdb from command line...

But it seems that it did get started, without complains about python ?

The warnings at start - could that mean that there is still hope, that it is possible to somehow configure gdb to run with Qt if it learns about its libraries ?

By the way... searching for the missing libraries...
[QT 4.8.4 debug libraries not found on Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14984769/qt-4-8-4-debug-libraries-not-found-on-mac-osx)

I have tried to replace my debugger (in Qt) using lldb and qmake - in both cases I got an error "Unable to create a debugger engine of the type 'No engine'"

**Edit:** Another suggestion I read about is to recompile Qt Creator Binaries to add debug symbols... I hope that is not what I have to do because

"Note: With Qt Creator 3.2 we drop support for OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard). The technical reason for this is that Apple does not support any kind of C++11 on that OS version. Of course that does not affect on which platforms you can run your Qt applications on. But it is not possible to run the Qt Creator 3.2 binaries on 10.6, and it also is not possible to compile Qt Creator 3.2 on 10.6 with the tool chains provided by Apple." (from release notes)

**Update:** I was able to find the cause of the error above (the KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS) by placing a zillion qDebug() statements... Though that was not what I am trying to accomplish, one error out of many.

I still have lots of errors... Attaching a debugger would be wonderful. I have listed the required libs for the program - they seem to exist. Not sure if they are "debug" or "release" libraries. .... But I am not trying to step through the Qt sources, so why would it matter if I have debug symbols for them ? And if they were "release" type libs, then my whole program, build in "debug", would not execute or even fail to build ? Since I am building my code in "Debug" mode and it executes, the libraries must be correct, right ?

So confusing...

Comment: Try running gdb on the command line with a call to "gdb /path/to/application.app" and see if that has the same problem. Once gdb has started, type "run" to start debugging.

Comment: @Merlin069, I tried - please see edit... maybe there is still hope ?

Comment: If you run otool -L on the binary in the app bundle, it will show you where it's looking for those libraries. Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780602/automatically-include-qt-libraries-in-the-app-bundle-deploying-in-mac/18781575#18781575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QtCreator 3.2 (and a few versions before that) requires a GDB that has Python scripting enabled (or LLDB, or CDB on Windows). On Mac, Apple's GDB doesn't have Python scripting, and therefore cannot be use with Qt Creator. FSF GDB works for some projects on Mac, but in general LLDB is preferable there.

Your "GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518)" is such an non-Python-enabled Apple build.